# Functions with asymmetrically decreasing Fourier transform?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, cv.complex-variables

$\def\ii{{\rm i}}\def\bbR{\mathbb R}\def\bbC{\mathbb C}\def\bbNo{\mathbb N_0}\def\Fou{\mathscr F}$Specifically, I would like to have a compactly supported continuous function $f=u+\ii\,v:\bbR\to\bbC$ with $u,v:\bbR\to\bbR$ such that $u$ is even and $v$ is odd, and such that also $\lim_{s\to-\infty\,} s^k\Fou f(s)=0$ holds for all $k\in\bbNo$ and $\lim_{s\to+\infty\,} s^k\Fou f(s)\not=0$ holds for some $k\in\bbNo$. Continuity may be replaced by integrability, if it makes matters easier.

The background here is that I would like to have an example of a distribution $T$ with nonsymmetric wave front set, and finding a function $f$ as above would be a first step towards that goal. By definition, the [wave front set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_front_set#Definition) is a bundle $C$ of conical subsets in the contangent bundle, and looking at the definition gives the impression that it may well happen that there are $\xi\in C$ with $-\xi\not\in C$. If one considers real valued distributions, mapping real valued test functions to real numbers, on an open set in a Euclidean space, it is easily seen that the wave front set is symmetric, noting that then $\Fou T(-\xi)=\overline{\Fou T(\xi)}$ holds. So only a truly complex valued distribution may have nonsymmetric wave front set.

By the [Paley–Wiener–Schwartz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem#Schwartz%27s_Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem) one could try to find $T$ on $\bbR$ as required by first finding an entire function $g:\bbC\to\bbC$ with suitable growth conditions, and such that $\lim_{s\to-\infty\,} s^kg(s)=0$ holds for all $k\in\bbNo$ and $\lim_{s\to+\infty\,} s^k g(s)\not=0$ holds for some $k\in\bbNo$.

**Additional question.** Does there exist an entire $g$ as above?

Comment: For any decreasing bound $0<M(x)\le 1$ with $\int_0^{\infty} |\log M|/(1+x^2)\, dx<\infty$, one can build an entire function of exponential type as a product $F(z)=\prod \sin a_n z/(a_n z)$ satisfying $|F(x)|\le M(|x|)$. If one could fine tune things here to make sure the bound is (almost) attained occasionally, then the desired function could be obtained as $G(z)=F(z) \sin^2\sqrt{z}/z$, where $F$ is as above with bound $e^{-2|x|^{1/2}}$.

Comment: Are you able to expand the above? What are the $a_n$? It seems to me that $G\,|\,\mathbb R$ cannot satisfy the (non)limit condition at $+\infty$ if the bound $|F(x)|\le{\rm e}^{-2|x|^{1/2}}$ holds.

Comment: (In my suggestion for $G$, I switched the roles of $\pm\infty$ compared to your conditions.) The $a_n$'s need to decrease sufficiently rapidly, depending on what $M$ is. The construction is discussed in Koosis, The logarithmic integral 1, and presumably in other places as well. This is also due to Paley and Wiener.

Comment: I'm not very optimistic about the approach since the kind of precise control on $\prod \sin a_nz/a_nz$ needed for this to work is probably very difficult to achieve, but at least it's half an idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edited.

$f=u+iv$, where $u$ is even and $v$ is odd is equivalent to
$f(-x)=\overline{f(x)}$. A function has this property if and only if its Fourier transform is real.

Boundedness of support of $f$ is equivalent to the
condition that the
Fourier transform $F=\hat{f}$ is entire of exponential type.

So we need to find a real entire function $F$ satisfying your conditions at $\pm\infty$. We construct it in the form
$$F(s)=\int_{-\infty}^x g(x)dx,$$
where $g$ is a real entire function of exponential type which tends to $0$ sufficiently fast as $x\to\pm\infty$, and
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)dx\neq 0.$$
For this one can use the [Beurling-Malliavin theorem](https://zbmath.org/0127.32601): For every uniformly continuous function $w\geq 1$ such that
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{w(x)}{1+x^2}dx<\infty,$$
there exists an entire function of (arbitrarily small) exponential type such that $ge^w$ is bounded. We can choose $w(x)=\sqrt{|x|+1}$ to make sure that $g$ decreases faster than any power.

Now it is easy to make $g$ positive on the real line. Notice that $g(x+i\epsilon)$ has the same rate of decrease on the real line (by a simple estimate), so $g(z+i\epsilon)\overline{g(\overline{z}-i\epsilon)}$ satisfies all needed conditions.

Comment: will the inverse Fourier transform of $F(s)=1/(s+1)^k$ be compactly supported?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: No, of course not. If $f$ were compactly supported, then $F$ would be entire.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko The conditions I posed on $f$, in particular having compact support, imply that $\mathscr Ff$, extended to $\mathbb C$, be entire. So your suggestion for getting $f$ does not work. See the "additional question".

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker: I did not notice this condition. Thanks. I edited my answer.

Comment: @Christian Remling: I edited my answer.

Comment: And if we want a slightly stronger decay on the positive side, we can just divide by a few (pairs of conjugate) zeroes, right? Also as @ChristianRemling explained in the comments to the original question, for even decreasing $w$ you don't even need the full strength of Beurling--Malliavin, there's a simple construction.

Comment: @Aleksei Kulikov: If we divide on few zeros, this will make a decrease on both sides, symmetrically. And you are right: when the weight $w$ is monotone, it is simple, and probably due to Wiener/Paley.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko OP asks for a very strong decay on one side, and a moderate decay on the other. Dividing by 10 zeroes will not change that.

Comment: @Aleksei Kulirov:  In my construction the function tends to a non-zero limit on one side, and decreases faster than any power, on the other side. Dividing it on a power or multiplying on a power will result to behavior like this power on one side and descrease faster than any power on the other side.

Comment: And that's exactly what the OP asked for, no?

Comment: @Aleksei Kulikov: yes, exactly.

Comment: @AlekseiKulikov or Alexandre Eremenko Question about "divide by a few (pairs of conjugate) zeroes"/"divide on few zeros". What precisely do you mean by this? If an entire function is divided by a nonconstant polynomial, the result is no longer entire, right?

Comment: @TaQ: Our entire function has infinitely many zeros. Therefore there are polynomials of arbitrarily high degree on which it can be divided, and the result is still entire.

Comment: If you take $F=\int_{-\infty}g$ as in your answer with $g$ the product in Christian Remling's comment, then of course $g$ has infinitely many zeros, but what guarantees that $F$ will have? If you take $g$ as in your answer, what guarantees the existence of zeros for $F$ then?

Comment: @TaQ: The only entire functions of exponential type with finitely many zeros are $P(z)e^{az}$, and it is clear that our function $F$ is not of this form: otherwise $g$ will be also of this form, and a function of this form cannot decrease fast on both sides of the real line, as our g does.

Comment: So the only entire functions of exponential type with no zeros must be $z\mapsto C{\rm e}^{az}$ with $C\not=0$. Is there a simple proof for this, e.g. by Rouché's theorem, or is it "deep"? Is there a reference?

Answer (score 2):

I suddenly realized that there is a simple explicit way of getting the function $f_1=F$ in Alexandre Eremenko's answer. Just for record, I put it here as an answer. The idea is to take as $g$ the Fourier transform of any even compactly supported real valued smooth function $\varphi$ with $\varphi(0)\not=0$, noting that then $\int_{\,\mathbb R}\mathscr F\varphi=C\varphi(0)$ for a certain nonzero $C$, depending on what precise definition of Fourier transform one uses. Taking $\varphi$ given by $t\mapsto{\rm e}^{(t^2-1)^{-1}}$ for $|t|<1$ and $0$ otherwise, we get
$$
f_1:\mathbb C\owns z\mapsto\frac\pi{2{\rm e}} + z\int_0^1\int_0^1\cos(\tau\,z \,t)\,{\rm e}^{\frac1{t^2-1}}{\rm d\,}t\,{\rm d\,}\tau\,.
$$
Now $\mathscr F\varphi$, extended to be defined on $\mathbb C$ is entire and of the exponential type considered in the [Paley–Wiener–Schwartz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem#Schwartz%27s_Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem) and in addition $\mathscr F\varphi\,|\,\mathbb R$ being in $\mathscr S(\mathbb R)$ decreases faster than any power. It follows that $f_1$ has essentially the same properties except that at $+\infty$ it has the limit value $\int_{\,\mathbb R}\mathscr F\varphi=\pi\,\varphi(0)={\rm e}^{-1}\pi\,$. Consequently $T=\mathscr F^{-1}(f_1|\,\mathbb R)$ is a compactly supported distribution on $\mathbb R$ that is not (given by) a smooth, not even continuous function. Since its Fourier transform $f_1$ has different kind of decay at $+\infty$ and $-\infty$, by Paley–Wiener–Schwartz we know that at least over some point it has a wave front (cotangent )vector $\xi$ with $-\xi$ not such.

Taking finitely many tensor products of $T$ with itself, we get examples of compactly supported distributions on $\mathbb R^n$ for any $n\in\mathbb N$, such that the wave front cone at least over some point is contained in the "corner" cone $[\,0\,,+\infty\,[^{\,n}$, and composing by suitable linear transforms, one can get examples where the wave front cone is arbitrarily sharp.